# How to send a Disconnect-Request using java?

Tags: java, freeradius, tinyradius

I was able to send an **Access-Request** to **Freeradius** server and get **Access-Accept**, using **tinyradius** library in a spring boot application. Now I need to send a **COA Request** and then a **Disconnect-Request** to end the session.

I tried to send a COA-Request, and I get an error.

```
> 2019-07-23 08:11:26.383  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
> org.tinyradius.util.RadiusClient         : communication failure,
> retry 1 2019-07-23 08:11:29.387  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
> org.tinyradius.util.RadiusClient         : communication failure,
> retry 2 2019-07-23 08:11:32.391 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
> org.tinyradius.util.RadiusClient         : communication failure
> (timeout), no more retries
```

```
RadiusClient rc = new RadiusClient("172.17.0.2", "testing123");
CoaRequest coaRequest=new CoaRequest();
coaRequest.setAuthenticator(dto.getAuthenticator().getBytes());

RadiusPacket response = rc.communicate(coaRequest,3799);
```

I get **'Receive timed out'** error and the request doesn't seem to hit the server either. I would like to know how to send the COA-Request and Disconnect-Request using Tinyradius library